# How to handle dialog.onclose event in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I try to use handle the event `onclose` of a `dialog` in Blazor. I tried to use the `@onclose` attribute but it doesn't work.

```
<dialog @onclose="MyEventHandler">
</dialog>

@code {    
    async Task MyEventHandler()
    {
    }
}
```

This produce the following error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@onclose' is not a valid attribute name.
System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@onclose' is not a valid attribute name.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
```

Is it possible to handle this event in Blazor?

Environment:

- Blazor - Server Side rendering
- .NET Core 3.1

Comment: I tried this out and do not get the error you get, but it also doesn't get triggeredon close....
A real hacky way to do this would be to do a JS event that onclose, does something to a hidden element that fires an event that Blazor can actually handle... Hopefully someone has a far less janky way to accomplish this.

Comment: I've writting a post about wrapping the dialog element in Blazor: https://www.meziantou.net/modal-component-in-blazor.htm?utm_medium=social&utm_source=stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to implement dialogs as the `<dialog>` tag isn't widely supported (Edge, IE, Safari don't support it). Consider https://github.com/Blazored/Modal as one example.

But it can be done. You can set then `open` attribute to a Blazor value, and set to null when you want to hide the dialog (this removed the attribute). I've create a simple demo (link below).

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/qq3osesu

Note that this will only work on FireFox/Chrome.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't answer the question. I don't want to close the dialog but to be notified when the dialog closed using the event.

BTW, I only target chromium based browsers so `dialog` is ok and less buggy when using `showModal()` than css based modals.

Answer (score 1):

you can define close method and call it inside of click command:

```
public void Close()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        ShowBackdrop = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

and click command is as below:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="() => Close()" style="float:left;">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="left;">&times;</span>
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put a square-shaped block through a circular hole.  It's very easy to use Blazor components to toggle on-and-off.  Trying to use an unpopular html tag and catch JavaScript events is not necessary.